# Modem not reconnectiong after 4G disconnect

Tags: networkmanager, modem

In one of our systems we recently had the problem that after a disconnect from the 4G network the modem did not reestablish the connection, even thought the 4G connection was back up again. A manual reboot of the machine was required to get it to reconnect. Since our machines are on remote locations, this is very inconvenient. That is why I would like to understand what happened and how we can avoid this in the future.

I am quite new to Linux, so apologies if I am asking an obvious question. I've tried an internet search on most of the lines in the log file, but this didn't help me much.

You can find some logs below. These are the logs of when the problem started, but towards the end also show the continuous connection loop that the system went through until we did a reboot.

If someone can help me to understand what is going on here and how this can be avoided that would be great. Thanks for your help!

**System info:**

- Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- Modem: Huawei ME909s-120
- Modem manager version: 1.12.2
- Network manager version: 1.10.6

**Logs**

```
Jan 29 23:41:02   ModemManager[836]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: 3GPP Registration state changed (roaming -> idle)
Jan 29 23:41:02   ModemManager[836]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (connected -> enabled)
Jan 29 23:41:02   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341262.8456] modem["ttyUSB0"]: modem state changed, 'connected' --> 'enabled' (reason: unknown)
Jan 29 23:41:02   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341262.8457] device (ttyUSB0): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'modem-no-carrier', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 29 23:41:02   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341262.8463] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jan 29 23:41:02   NetworkManager[746]: <warn>  [1580341262.8600] device (ttyUSB0): Activation: failed for connection 'lte0'
Jan 29 23:41:02   dbus-daemon[682]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.8' (uid=0 pid=746 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Jan 29 23:41:02   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341262.8638] device (ttyUSB0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 29 23:41:02   kernel: [3073082.377544] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wwp0s20u3c2: link is not ready
Jan 29 23:41:02   systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jan 29 23:41:02   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341262.8696] policy: auto-activating connection 'lte0'
Jan 29 23:41:02   ModemManager[836]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (enabled -> disconnecting)
Jan 29 23:41:02   ModemManager[836]: <warn>  Couldn't find associated cdc-wdm port for 'net/wwp0s20u3c2'
Jan 29 23:41:02   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341262.8759] modem["ttyUSB0"]: modem state changed, 'enabled' --> 'disconnecting' (reason: user-requested)
Jan 29 23:41:02   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341262.8774] device (ttyUSB0): Activation: starting connection 'lte0' (3a37dbea-8a70-44ed-87ae-3330cadd316c)
Jan 29 23:41:02   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341262.8783] device (ttyUSB0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 29 23:41:02   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341262.8786] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jan 29 23:41:02   ModemManager[836]: <info>  Simple connect started...
Jan 29 23:41:02   ModemManager[836]: <info>  Simple connect state (4/8): Wait to get fully enabled
Jan 29 23:41:02   dbus-daemon[682]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jan 29 23:41:02   systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jan 29 23:41:02   nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wwp0s20u3c2]: new request (1 scripts)
Jan 29 23:41:02   nm-dispatcher: req:1 'down' [wwp0s20u3c2]: start running ordered scripts...
Jan 29 23:41:02   nm-dispatcher: req:2 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
Jan 29 23:41:02   ModemManager[836]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (disconnecting -> connected)
Jan 29 23:41:02   ModemManager[836]: <info>  Simple connect state (5/8): Register
Jan 29 23:41:02   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341262.9043] modem["ttyUSB0"]: modem state changed, 'disconnecting' --> 'connected' (reason: user-requested)
Jan 29 23:41:02   nm-dispatcher: req:2 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Jan 29 23:41:02   ModemManager[836]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: 3GPP Registration state changed (idle -> searching)
Jan 29 23:42:02   ModemManager[836]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: 3GPP Registration state changed (searching -> idle)
Jan 29 23:42:02   ModemManager[836]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (connected -> enabled)
Jan 29 23:42:02   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341322.9355] modem["ttyUSB0"]: modem state changed, 'connected' --> 'enabled' (reason: unknown)
Jan 29 23:42:02   NetworkManager[746]: <warn>  [1580341322.9602] modem-broadband[ttyUSB0]: failed to connect modem: Network timeout
Jan 29 23:42:02   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341322.9603] device (ttyUSB0): state change: prepare -> failed (reason 'gsm-registration-timeout', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 29 23:42:02   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341322.9609] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jan 29 23:42:02   NetworkManager[746]: <warn>  [1580341322.9620] device (ttyUSB0): Activation: failed for connection 'lte0'
Jan 29 23:42:02   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341322.9648] device (ttyUSB0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 29 23:42:02   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341322.9669] policy: auto-activating connection 'lte0'
Jan 29 23:42:02   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341322.9703] device (ttyUSB0): Activation: starting connection 'lte0' (3a37dbea-8a70-44ed-87ae-3330cadd316c)
Jan 29 23:42:02   ModemManager[836]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (enabled -> disconnecting)
Jan 29 23:42:02   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341322.9709] device (ttyUSB0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 29 23:42:02   ModemManager[836]: <warn>  Couldn't find associated cdc-wdm port for 'net/wwp0s20u3c2'
Jan 29 23:42:02   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341322.9713] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jan 29 23:42:02   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341322.9748] modem["ttyUSB0"]: modem state changed, 'enabled' --> 'disconnecting' (reason: user-requested)
Jan 29 23:42:02   ModemManager[836]: <info>  Simple connect started...
Jan 29 23:42:02   ModemManager[836]: <info>  Simple connect state (4/8): Wait to get fully enabled
Jan 29 23:42:03   ModemManager[836]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (disconnecting -> connected)
Jan 29 23:42:03   ModemManager[836]: <info>  Simple connect state (5/8): Register
Jan 29 23:42:03   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341323.0029] modem["ttyUSB0"]: modem state changed, 'disconnecting' --> 'connected' (reason: user-requested)
Jan 29 23:42:03   ModemManager[836]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: 3GPP Registration state changed (idle -> searching)
Jan 29 23:42:26   ModemManager[836]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: 3GPP Registration state changed (searching -> registering)
Jan 29 23:42:27   ModemManager[836]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: 3GPP Registration state changed (registering -> roaming)
Jan 29 23:42:29   ModemManager[836]: <info>  Simple connect state (6/8): Bearer
Jan 29 23:42:29   NetworkManager[746]: <warn>  [1580341349.9281] modem-broadband[ttyUSB0]: failed to connect modem: Cannot create new bearer: all existing bearers are connected
Jan 29 23:42:29   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341349.9282] device (ttyUSB0): state change: prepare -> failed (reason 'unknown', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 29 23:42:29   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341349.9288] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jan 29 23:42:29   NetworkManager[746]: <warn>  [1580341349.9299] device (ttyUSB0): Activation: failed for connection 'lte0'
Jan 29 23:42:29   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341349.9318] device (ttyUSB0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 29 23:42:29   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341349.9339] policy: auto-activating connection 'lte0'
Jan 29 23:42:29   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341349.9374] device (ttyUSB0): Activation: starting connection 'lte0' (3a37dbea-8a70-44ed-87ae-3330cadd316c)
Jan 29 23:42:29   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341349.9382] device (ttyUSB0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jan 29 23:42:29   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341349.9388] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jan 29 23:42:29   ModemManager[836]: <info>  Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (connected -> disconnecting)
Jan 29 23:42:29   ModemManager[836]: <warn>  Couldn't find associated cdc-wdm port for 'net/wwp0s20u3c2'
Jan 29 23:42:29   NetworkManager[746]: <info>  [1580341349.9436] modem["ttyUSB0"]: modem state changed, 'connected' --> 'disconnecting' (reason: user-requested)
```